# How to properly reference the path with newly installed packages using npm in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, reactjs, laravel-5

I've installed ReactJS and Babel using npm in my laravel project. They are found in "node_modules" folder created by npm itself. But the problem is my react code doesn't seem to work if I import using this code:

```
<script src="node_modules/react/react.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/browser.js"></script>
```

Is the format of the path correct? because if I just import using this type of code for all my imports required for ReactJS:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
```

It seems to work if I just use the internet for getting the packages.

My react code is here:

```
<div id="myapp"></div>
<!-- JavaScripts -->
<script type="text/babel">
    var BuckyComponent = React.createClass({
        render: function()  {
            return(
                <h2>{this.props.user} likes to eat {this.props.food}</h2>
            );
        }
    });

    React.render(
        <div>
            <BuckyComponent user="Arth" food="Bacon"/>
            <BuckyComponent user="Arth" food="Pork"/>
            <BuckyComponent user="Arth" food="Chicken"/>
        </div>,
        document.getElementById('myapp')
    );
</script>
```

Comment: That depends on the location of `node_modules`, is it in the webroot?

Comment: @Ciccio yes it's in the root

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way you use Npm/Bower packages within Laravel. Either package manager will store its files outside the Laravel *public* folder, the first inside `node_modules` and the later inside `bower_components`. So they're not intended to be publicly available.

So how would you use their packages within Laravel? Using build systems like [Laravel Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir), just the [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or even the [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

It's all up to you to copy the *distribution* files of React and Babel, concat them, minify them and the like. You'll end up with them inside the *public* folder, but before you'll want to do a nice concatenation and minification of all that stuff to serve the smallest possible number of files and their sizes.